# how to make a .exe file for windows form application in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports-2010

I'm using Microsoft visual studio 2010 professional to develop a project on the windows application. I stuck with how i can create the .exe file for the windows form application and even how can i integrate Crystal report with the same exe file? I've done with the following:

1. setup project was created
2. I've merged the modules (creddist2005_x86.msm)

By doing all this; the setup was running fine. But, crystal reports were not generated.

Comment: while merging the DLLs you will need to add Crystal Report DLL also in the setup

Comment: @Murtaza I've already merge the .msm file while creating the setup.

Comment: But its giving error as " Could not load file or assembly CrystalDecision.CrystalReport.Engine.Version13.0.2000.0. Culture neutral"

Comment: refer to the below URL for your reference - this has clear steps to create a setup with crystal report - http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Using+Crystal+Reports+for+Visual+Studio+2010+Merge+Modules+(MSM)+to+create+a+Setup+project

Comment: The year 2005 was of course a while ago, there was no version 13 yet back then.  You are simply installing the wrong version.